# Remove Green Screen Background from Image Using R

Tags: r, image, image-processing

I took a photo in front of a green screen and saved it as PNG file on my computer. Consider the following example PNG:

[image]

I can read this image to R as shown below:

```
library("magick")
my_img <- image_read("my_image.png")
```

How can I remove the green screen background and export the image without background as PNG using the R programming language?

Comment: Have a look at the `imager ` package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/imager/vignettes/gettingstarted.html

Comment: @denis Thanks a lot for the hint. Unfortunately, I didn't find any functions for background/green screen removal in the imager package. Could you give me another hint for a specific function or section of the vignette?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should explore a bit more the package.
Here is a short example using the second vignette: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/imager/vignettes/pixsets.html

```
library(imager)

yourhand <- load.image("test.jpg")
plot(yourhand)

detect <-px.flood(yourhand,1,1,sigma = .3,high_connexity = T) 
highlight(detect)
```

[image]

```
yourhand[detect] <- 0
plot(yourhand)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the further explanations, this is exactly what I was looking for!